# ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'W_regularizer')

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

My Code:

```
model = Sequential()
#model.add(Dense(1, activation="relu", input_dim = X_train.shape[1]))
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim = X_train.shape[1], W_regularizer = l1(0.001)))

model.compile(loss = "mse", optimizer = "adam")
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'W_regularizer')
```

Comment: There is no such parameter as `W_regularizer` in TensorFlow, remove that.

Answer (score 2):

In the recent versions of Keras, `W_regularizer` is replaced with `kernel_regularizer`.
So try like this:

```
model = Sequential()
#model.add(Dense(1, activation="relu", input_dim = X_train.shape[1]))
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim = X_train.shape[1], kernel_regularizer = l1(0.001)))

model.compile(loss = "mse", optimizer = "adam")
```